# Scrapy - not retuning data

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I am trying to extract tweets from https://twitter.com/ABCTV. I know there is API and so this is just a learning exercise. My code returns zero tweets. My item definition:

```
import scrapy

class Tweet(scrapy.Item):       
    username = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    created_at= scrapy.Field()
    retweet_count = scrapy.Field()
```

My crawler definition:

```
class TwitterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "twitter"
    allowed_domains = ["https://twitter.com/mycpl"]
    start_urls = ["https://twitter.com/mycpl"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel=Selector(response)
        tweets=sel.xpath('//div[@class="content"]')
        items = [] 

    for tweet in tweets:
        item = Tweet()
        item['username']=tweet.xpath('.//*[starts-with(@class,"username")]//text()').extract()
        item['created_at']=tweet.xpath('.//*[starts-with(@class,"_timestamp")]//@data-time-ms').extract()
        item['retweet_count']=tweet.xpath('.//*[starts-with(@class,"ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation")]/text()').extract()
        item['data']=tweet.xpath('p//text()').extract()
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Please assist my learning and explain why I am not receiving any responses when I run scrapy crawl twitter -o test -t json.

Edited -- fixed xpath code and works (only 20 because of scroll infinite scroll issue)

Comment: You can't just directly scrape twitter .You need to use twitter api which allows 1000 hit daily. Twitter won't allow bots to crawl them unless you use their api or selenium in your code

Comment: I have just scraped Twitter using Scrapy. How is this true?

Comment: Your ip will be banned !!